# How do I change the HTML that is created with links in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to create a Wordpress template from static HTML that I made a while back. In the HTML there is a `<span>` tag within each link in the main navigation menu. It looks like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/52zgm8kpj8cfb51/Screenshot%202014-08-25%2018.35.47.png?dl=0

The span accounts for the small tab-like extension to the left of the links. This is to give the page a three-dimensional effect. Unfortunately, when I converted the HTML to a Wordpress theme, I was not able to find how to do this whilst making use of Wordpress' dynamic menu function. This creates the links automatically and generates the HTML. I was wondering if anyone knew a way in which I could edit the generated hyperlinks to include the `<span>` tag.

Comment: Edit your question to include the code you're using to generate the menu in your theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the `wp_nav_menu()` function to generate the menu links, I believe the code you're looking for is:

```
<?php
$defaults = array(
    'link_before'     => '<span>',
    'link_after'      => '</span>'
);
wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: Thanks for the help, but where would I put this piece of code?

Comment: You would place it wherever your theme is generating the menu.